# Construction of truncations in a $t$-structure

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-categories, triangulated-categories

I'm reading about $t$-structures in the book *D-Modules, Perverse Sheaves, and Representation Theory* by Hotta, Takeuchi, and Taniski. Given a $t$-structure $(\mathcal{D}^{\leq 0}, \mathcal{D}^{\geq 0})$ on a triangulated category $\mathcal{D}$, Proposition 8.1.4 shows that there is a right adjoint to the inclusion functor $\mathcal{D}^{\leq 0} \to \mathcal{D}$.

The proof begins by stating that, for $X \in \mathcal{D}$, it suffices to find $Z \in \mathcal{D}^{\leq 0}$ such that $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{D}}(Y, Z) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_\mathcal{D}(Y, X)$ for all $Y \in \mathcal{D}^{\leq 0}$. Why does this suffice?